# How to show flutter local notification while receiving push notification on foreground?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

Currently, I am using alert dialog to show the notification while receiving push notification while the app is in foreground. But I want to show something non-intrusive like local notification in flutter. How do I implement that in my application? Here is my current implementation:

```
FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
  @override
  void initState() {
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
            content: ListTile(
              title: Text(message['notification']['title']),
              subtitle: Text(message['notification']['body']),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: Text('Ok'),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
        print("onMessage: $message");
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onLaunch: $message");
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/notify');
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onResume: $message");
      },
    );
}
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Since I didn't get an answer I tried on my own and figured it out.

Do not forget to add the `flutter_local_notifications` library to your project for working this code
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications

**TESTED AND WORKING FOR ANDROID**

```dart
FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  @override
  void initState() {
var initializationSettingsAndroid =
        new AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
    var initializationSettingsIOS = new IOSInitializationSettings();
    var initializationSettings = new InitializationSettings(
        initializationSettingsAndroid, initializationSettingsIOS);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        showNotification(
            message['notification']['title'], message['notification']['body']);
        print("onMessage: $message");
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onLaunch: $message");
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/notify');
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onResume: $message");
      },
    );
}
Future onSelectNotification(String payload) async {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (_) {
        return new AlertDialog(
          title: Text("PayLoad"),
          content: Text("Payload : $payload"),
        );
      },
    );
  }
void showNotification(String title, String body) async {
    await _demoNotification(title, body);
  }

  Future<void> _demoNotification(String title, String body) async {
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'channel_ID', 'channel name', 'channel description',
        importance: Importance.Max,
        playSound: true,
        sound: 'sound',
        showProgress: true,
        priority: Priority.High,
        ticker: 'test ticker');

    var iOSChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();
    var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
        androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOSChannelSpecifics);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .show(0, title, body, platformChannelSpecifics, payload: 'test');
  }
```

It works like a charm. Hopefully will help someone out :)

Comment: @rebar did this happen to work for you on IOS? I am attempting to do something similar and am still having some trouble.

Comment: Thanks for answer!
Do not forget add flutter_local_notifications library to your project for working this code.

Comment: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'AndroidNotificationSound'

How can I set the sound property?

Comment: @AliHaider I think now you have to add sound in raw folder inside android/app/src/main/res/raw/sound.mp3. Now it is ```sound:RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('sound')``` .

Comment: Do we need to configure it on main.dart or anywhere else. Also, if i am at different pages then does notification will be visible during onMessage event, or need to define it everywhere?

Comment: @Rocx No you don't need to configure it everywhere. But it is better to configure it on the first screen. If you have the login page, you can configure it after user logs in successfully. Point is do it only once. And make the function singleton using get_it library to make sure only one instance of the notification handler is running.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i haven't used get_it. Do you have any example? I am trying your code but till now struggling. on your code when i click the notification my app is terminated. Also, it is opening new instance of the app.

Comment: In case you are interested here is the question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65166526

Comment: This notification goes straight to the notification tray without first showing itself to the user on top, like an overlay. This is unlike how Whatsapp notifications work, which is also what I like to have in Flutter. 
Edit: these are called *High priority notifications

Answer (score 3):

I made this class with a static method init() and call it once from initState of first page of my app

```
const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
  'my_channel', // id
  'My Channel', // title
  'Important notifications from my server.', // description
  importance: Importance.high,
);

class Notifications {
  static Future init() async {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
    
    final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
        FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

    await FirebaseMessaging.instance
        .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    );

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      RemoteNotification notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification android = message.notification?.android;
      if (notification != null && android != null) {
        flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
            notification.hashCode,
            notification.title,
            notification.body,
            NotificationDetails(
              android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                channel.id,
                channel.name,
                channel.description,
                icon: 'some_icon_in_drawable_folder',
              ),
            ));
      }
    });
  }
}
```