# Flutter Firebase foreground push notification not showing but background is working

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

It's been few days since I've been trying to solve this problem. I have implemented firebase messaging for push notification, as a result, I am **able to receive notification when the app is in background**, but **not able to receive it when the app is in foreground**. I tried every solution possible or on stackoverflow/github but nothing worked so far. The following are the sources which I tried:

[stackoverflow solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62689199/17091737)

[stackoverflow solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60850443/17091737)

Current code =>

`NotificationService.dart`:

```
class NotificationService {
  static final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  static Future initialize() async {
    final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
        FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

    AndroidInitializationSettings androidInitializationSettings =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');

    InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(android: androidInitializationSettings);

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
      initializationSettings,
      // onSelectNotification: doSomething(),
    );
  }

  static Future showNotification(RemoteMessage message) async {
    AndroidNotificationDetails androidDetails = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      "default_notification_channel_id",
      "channel",
      enableLights: true,
      enableVibration: true,
      priority: Priority.high,
      importance: Importance.max,
      largeIcon: DrawableResourceAndroidBitmap("ic_launcher"),
      styleInformation: MediaStyleInformation(
        htmlFormatContent: true,
        htmlFormatTitle: true,
      ),
      playSound: true,
    );

    await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        message.data.hashCode,
        message.data['title'],
        message.data['body'],
        NotificationDetails(
          android: androidDetails,
        ));
  }
}
```

`main.dart`:

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  print('Handling a background message ${message.messageId}');
  print('Notification Message: ${message.data}');
  NotificationService.showNotification(message);
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  runApp(
    MyApp(),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    NotificationService.initialize();
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      NotificationService.showNotification(message);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(...)
```

One more point to add, when the app is in **background** (the case where I can receive notification), I get the output of the first 2 `print` statements i.e. `message.messageId` and `message.data`:

```
I/flutter ( 3363): Handling a background message 0:1637822186109880%5dd28a92f9fd7ecd
I/flutter ( 3363): Notification Message: {body: Price is at Bull! Buy Now!, title: Hello Traders!}
```

But when the app is in **foreground** (the case where I do not receive notification), I get the following output: `D/FLTFireMsgReceiver( 3363): broadcast received for message`

It would really help if someone could help me out, It's been days debugging, finding solution.
Thank you!

`AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.trading_app">

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

   <application
        android:label="TradingApp"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <meta-data         
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"                 
            android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />

        <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
        </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />

            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
            <!-- <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="high_importance_channel" /> -->
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: any updates on this, i am also facing the same issue?

Answer (score 5):

Adding this snippet from the [docs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/notifications/#foreground-notifications) helped me to solve this issue.

```
await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
  alert: true, // Required to display a heads up notification
  badge: true,
  sound: true,
);
```

Comment: This only works with Apple devices. "Sets the presentation options for Apple notifications when received in the foreground."

Answer (score 3):

I dont know if it will work or not for you, but here is my code to show notification when app on foreground. I put messageHandler on initState(). `LocalNotification` is a custom class, so you can either create a same class, or just put whatever inside `showNotification` to `onMessage`

```
  Future<void> messageHandler() async {
  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  );

  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage event) {
    LocalNotification.showNotification(event);
  });

}

  static Future<void> showNotification(RemoteMessage payload) async {

    var android = AndroidInitializationSettings('logo_rs');
    var initiallizationSettingsIOS = IOSInitializationSettings();
    var initialSetting = new InitializationSettings(android: android, iOS: initiallizationSettingsIOS);
    final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initialSetting);



    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidDetails = AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'default_notification_channel_id',
        'Notification',
        'All Notification is Here',
        importance: Importance.max,
        priority: Priority.high,
        ticker: 'ticker',
        icon: "logo_rs",
        playSound: true,
        sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound("notification")
    );
    const iOSDetails = IOSNotificationDetails();
    const NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(android: androidDetails, iOS: iOSDetails);

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(0, payload.notification!.title, payload.notification!.body, platformChannelSpecifics);
  }
```

Add try to put this on your AndroidManifest

```
   <meta-data  android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
                android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />
```

String.xml (new file inside res/values)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<resources>
    <string name="default_notification_channel_id" translatable="false">fcm_default_channel</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but I don't think so there is anything I missed according to your answer! Still it's not showing and there's no error...

Comment: Try putting this in your AndroidManifest
`<meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
                android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />`
And change your cahnnel ID to 'default_notification_channel_id'

Comment: I did as you told but I'm getting the following error while debugging (build failed): `Element meta-data#com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id at AndroidManifest.xml:61:13-63:55 duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml:16:9-18:71`. I think this is because of duplicate `meta-data` ?. I have edited the question with `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: Okay, that was because there was a duplicate `meta-data` (the last one), I commented that and it build successfully but still, I cannot see the foreground notification, background notification working as usual...

Answer (score 1):

Try invoking the code below inside `main()` right after initialisation code for FlutterLocalNotification

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
    // handle message here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage/#foreground-messages),

> To listen to messages whilst your application is in the foreground, listen to the `onMessage` stream.

So, you should print your message id and data there.

In your MyApp initState,

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
  // print foreground message here.
  print('Handling a foreground message ${message.messageId}');
  print('Notification Message: ${message.data}');

  if (message.notification != null) {
    print('Message also contained a notification: ${message.notification}');
  }

  //.. rest of your code
  NotificationService.showNotification(message);
});
```

Comment: Still, the same output, and how does checking some print statements solve the problem?

Comment: Your problem was that foreground notification was not showing. My code above would confirm that your device received it. Then you know the error is from `showNotification()`. When you say "same output", does your code print "handling a foreground message..."?

Comment: No, it doesn't print `Handling a foreground message`, it just prints `D/FLTFireMsgReceiver( 2809): broadcast received for message`. Okay, I get your point, so what could be wrong in `showNotification` because it is working with `background`...

Answer (score 0):

After struggling a lot with this I found the solution. The problem was that I was sending the message the wrong way inside the firebase console. When u are creating the notification inside the firebase console, locate the "Send test message" button (it should be above the images showing u the notification preview).

[image]

To send a test message u have to put a token. This token is obtained by code with:

```
_getDevToken() async{
String? token = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
print("DEV TOKEN FIREBASE CLOUD MESSAGING -> $token");
}
```

Also, remember to put the android channel id in the last step or your background notification won't find the method to be handled.
Happy coding y'all!

Answer (score 0):

Hi I also faced the same issue, firebase messaging was working fine for me . I was using
firebase_messaging: ^11.2.8
flutter_local_notifications: ^9.3.2

When I run "flutter pub get" it changed to latest version of both this packages that made the problem. When we use ^ before version number while we adding packages to pubspec.yaml it will automatically update to latest version when update.
My solution is - I cleared the cache folder from flutter/bin directory , and I removed ^ from pubspec.yaml package version name.Then run the project.

Answer (score 0):

As for me, the same issue persisted when I used the emulator; however when I generated an apk file of the app and tried. The notification was delivered.