# Notification push if is close with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have finish a app, notification push is work but it only works if I leave the app open all the time. If I close, the notification push don't work and it doesn't check.

But, the every social as Facebook, Instagram and TikTok if I close alls app, works the notification push...

How do you do it or how is the specific code so that the push notification also checks if the app is closed or not in use?

Notification push work if the app is close or don't use

Comment: How do you send notifications in your app ? In my case, I use https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications and it sends notifications even if my app is closed. Have a look at that package.

Comment: Please share you code for handling notification.

Comment: You can refer this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70106773/flutter-firebase-foreground-push-notification-not-showing-but-background-is-work

Comment: what are you using for push notification?

Comment: Thank you very much but I have use awesome_notifications is work only if I use the app, if I hide or close the app don't work and don't read the notification...

For you, awesome_notifications could it still work if the app is closed or hidden? What and how I resolve the function?